# Handling large database interaction in hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jdbc, java-8

I have a code base where a listener interacts with MySql database, this listener gets huge number of records from a queue (ActiveMQ) which must be stored in database.

The problem is when large datasets are to be entered into database hibernate throws exception which is:-

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

Did anyone encounter the same problem?! I tried synchronizing the method which is in the Listener but when I do so the Messages from Queue gets Stuck.

This is the stacktrace:-

```
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:493)
11:42:59,330 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:904)
11:42:59,332 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:857)
11:42:59,334 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:203)
11:42:59,336 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:42:59,337 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/omoto
11:42:59,338 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
11:42:59,339 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
11:42:59,341 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
11:42:59,342 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     ... 28 more
11:42:59,343 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/omoto
11:42:59,345 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:390)
11:42:59,346 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
11:42:59,348 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
11:42:59,350 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
11:42:59,352 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     ... 30 more
11:42:59,352 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
11:42:59,354 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:377)
11:42:59,356 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
11:42:59,357 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
11:42:59,359 ERROR [stderr] (crmMessageListenerContainer-4)     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
```

Here's the config code:-

hibernate.cfg.xml:-

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

persistance.xml:-

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size"
                    value="5"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size"
                    value="20"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout"
                    value="300"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"
                    value="50"/>
          <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"
                    value="3000"/>
```

Comment: At minimum post the full exception stacktrace, as it will likely contain the underlying cause.

Comment: posted stacktrace, hope it helps!

Comment: That is not the full stacktrace, just a fragment that ends abruptly.

Comment: Yeah I could capture only that much of it, as the logs were too fast and all were mixed up

Comment: Log to file instead of to console, and you shouldn't have that problem. That most important details for your error are deep in the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Okay I found a better stacktrace now is this fine?

Comment: Yes, that exception suggests that you have exhausted your connection pool. You are likely not closing connections correctly, or you need to configure the pool to allocate more connections. Consider posting relevant code.

Comment: I have added the configuration codes as well please suggest me the appropriate number of pools to allocate connections @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Please show the code where you're using connections. I think it is more likely that you aren't closing connection correctly, and in any case, it is pretty hard to size a connection pool without intimate knowledge of the application and its runtime behavior.

Comment: Sorry I cant actually show you the code as it's way too lengthy, but I'm pretty sure the connections are closed properly, with a method which is "clientRegistrationDAO.commitTraction(session, false);", When ever a seesion is opened and after DB transactionis done it is being closed in the code that I can ensure you @MarkRotteveel